# Upload big file on Rails-API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, rack, rails-api

I wonder how manage on a rails-api the upload of a "big" file (arround 100m). Is it possible to stream to s3 the rack tempfile during the upload?

I'm creating a new service how just need to receive post request with parameters and files ask the original app if it's everything is ok, and process them. Lot's people over blogs tell that ruby is not the best language for that, it's not a problem to change.

So I would like to know if making a rails api who will received post, return status, and communicate with the other rails app is a good thing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible.  Amazon has their own [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/) Gem which provides the `s3` functionality.

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new
```

Here's how to [get started](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/index.html) using it.

This question however is a little off-topic because you show no proof of trial and error.

Comment: Thanks. I'm already using the aws sdk but if I have a big file, it still gonna host it locally before sending it to s3, no ?

Comment: you should be able to send the temp stream to s3, yes, but again - you don't show what you've tried so far.  what have you tried to do so far?